# XAML UI Virtualization

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm working on an app with a large GridView that requires virtualization. I had been setting a MaxWidth on the GridView so that I got the 'for-free' virtualization. However, I also have a requirement that the GridView scale across all displays - all the way up to 27" monitor with 2560x1440 resolution, so I'd put the GridView into a ViewBox:

```
        <Viewbox Margin="0,50,0,0" 
             Stretch="UniformToFill"
             StretchDirection="Both">
        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileDataTemplate}"
                  Style="{StaticResource GalleryGridView}">
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="0 0 2 2" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
    </Viewbox>
```

Problem here is that we're ending up with double scrollbars, because the app is initially designed for 1366x768 and the scale-up isn't quite matching. I'm pretty sure this could be overcome by us removing the MaxWidth, but then we'll lose the automatic UI virtualization. Is there a way to implement UI virtualization without setting a max width?

Viewbox is contained in a HubSection:

```
<Hub HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource OnDemandGalleryHubHeaderTemplate}"
     Style="{StaticResource BaseHubStyle}">

    <HubSection x:Name="PremiumNetworksHubSection"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource OnDemandGalleryHubSectionDataTemplate}"
                DataContext="{Binding PageData}"
                Margin="120,0,0,0"
                Style="{StaticResource OnDemandHubSectionStyle}"
                Template="{StaticResource GalleryHubSectionTemplate}" />
</Hub>
```

Following styles are set on the GridView in the ViewBox:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily"
        Value="Global User Interface" />
<Setter Property="SelectionMode"
        Value="None" />
<Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled"
        Value="False" />
<Setter Property="IsActiveView"
        Value="False" />
<Setter Property="IsDoubleTapEnabled"
        Value="False" />
<Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled"
        Value="False" />
<Setter Property="IsRightTapEnabled"
        Value="False" />
<Setter Property="IsTapEnabled"
        Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Width"
        Value="Auto" />
<Setter Property="MaxWidth"
        Value="1300" />
<Setter Property="Height"
        Value="589" />
<Setter Property="Margin"
        Value="0,0,0,0" />
<Setter Property="Padding"
        Value="0,0,0,0" />
```

Following styles are set on the HubSection:

```
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="40,40,40,44" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsHeaderInteractive"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="65,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="0,0,0,0" />
```

GridView Item Template:

```
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource TileGridStyle}">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GoToDetailsPageCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GetImageSourceFromTile}, ConverterParameter='h170'}"
               Width="227"
               Height="170" />
        <Rectangle Width="227"
                   Height="80"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000"
                                  Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#ff000000"
                                  Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TileLabel}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding QPChannelId, Converter={StaticResource GetImageSourceFromQpChannelId}, ConverterParameter='h30'}"
               Height="30"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="0,5,10,5" />
        <Border Visibility="{Binding IsNew, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                Style="{StaticResource TileNewLabelBorder}">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="NewIndicator"
                       Style="{StaticResource TileNewIndicatorLabel}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Styles for the Grid in the ItemTemplate:

```
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="227" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="170" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="0,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="IsTapEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
```

Comment: I would need more xaml code to identify the problem... the template to start with.

Comment: Added in more xaml information, thanks for your response